# Given two different vector subspaces of dimension $n-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given two different vector subspaces $H$ and $L$, both of them with dimension $n-1$, $n\geqslant 2$, how can I show that any vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the sum of a vector in $H$ and a vector in $L$?

I've tried with the following. If $H$ and $L$ are different, then $\exists x: x\in H $ and $x\notin L \iff x \in H\setminus L$. Then, let $\langle x \rangle$ be the subspace generated by $x$, using Grassman's formula, $dim(H+x) = dim(H)+dim(x) - dim(H\cap x)$. But since $H\cap x = x$, then both terms cancel out and I'm left with $dim(H+x) = n-1$. I'm really stuck. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hint:  since $L\neq H$ there is some vector $\vec v$ which is in $L$ but not in $H$.  Show that a basis for $H$ plus $\vec v$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Take a basis $B$ for $H$. Are you aware of the conditions under which $B\cup\{\mathbf{x}\}$ will be linearly independent? It has something to do with whether $\mathbf{x}$ lies or does not lie in the span of *something*...